# Mokito/Java - Static Methods Mock

Tags: java, mockito

For example I have the following classes below:

```
public class TesteEstatico {

   public static String teste(){
      return "FOO";
   }

}
```

And I have a class that uses her method:

```
public class UsaTesteEstatico {

   public String metodoParaTeste1 (){
       return  TesteEstatico.teste() + " BAR ";
   }

   public String metodoParaTeste2 (){
       return  "FOO "+TesteEstatico.teste() + " BAR ";
   }

}
```

Test class:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith; 
import org.mockito.InjectMocks; 
import org.mockito.Mockito; 
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) public class UsaTesteEstaticoTest {

   @InjectMocks
   UsaTesteEstatico usaTesteEstatico;

   @Test
   void teste1(){
       Mockito.mockStatic(TesteEstatico.class);
       Mockito.when(TesteEstatico.teste())
            .thenReturn("BANANA");

       String res = usaTesteEstatico.metodoParaTeste1();
       System.out.println(res);
   }

   @Test
   void teste2(){
       Mockito.mockStatic(TesteEstatico.class);
       Mockito.when(TesteEstatico.teste())
            .thenReturn("LARANJA");

       String res = usaTesteEstatico.metodoParaTeste2();
       System.out.println(res);

   }
}
```

Error I get when trying to run the tests:

org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
For TesteEstatico, static mocking is already registered in the current thread
To create a new mock, the existing static mock registration must be deregistered

Versions of the libs that are in the project:

- junit-jupiter 5.5.2
- mockito-junit-jupiter 3.2.14
- mockito-inline 3.2.14

Any idea how to solve this, i've tried a few things but nothing successful.

NOTE: I cannot change or add any new libraries as it is a restricted project.

Comment: Use a `@BeforeAll`-method to initialize the static mock instead of initializing it in each test.

Comment: @Lesiak  `Mockito.reset(Mockito.mockStatic(TesteEstatico.class))` it would be something similar to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use try-with-resources block in each of the tests to close the mockStatic.

```java
public class UsaTesteEstaticoTest {
    
    UsaTesteEstatico usaTesteEstatico = new UsaTesteEstatico();

    @Test
    void teste1(){
        try (var ms = Mockito.mockStatic(TesteEstatico.class)) {
            Mockito.when(TesteEstatico.teste()).thenReturn("BANANA");
            String res = usaTesteEstatico.metodoParaTeste1();
            System.out.println(res);
        }
    }

    @Test
    void teste2(){
        try (var ms = Mockito.mockStatic(TesteEstatico.class)) {
            Mockito.when(TesteEstatico.teste()).thenReturn("LARANJA");
            String res = usaTesteEstatico.metodoParaTeste2();
            System.out.println(res);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note on mockStatic in @BeforeAll**

Using `@BeforeAll` is a trap and bad advice.
You should strive for independent tests that don't affect each other.
This is not the case for mockStatic called in @BeforeAll, as stubbing from test methods outlive the test methods.

For example

```java
// BAD CODE DONT USE
public class UsaTesteEstaticoTest {

    UsaTesteEstatico usaTesteEstatico = new UsaTesteEstatico();
    static MockedStatic<TesteEstatico> ms;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void init() {
        ms = Mockito.mockStatic(TesteEstatico.class);
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void close() {
        ms.close();
    }


    @Test
    void teste1() {
        Mockito.when(TesteEstatico.teste()).thenReturn("BANANA");
        String res = usaTesteEstatico.metodoParaTeste1();
        System.out.println(res);
    }

    @Test
    void teste2() {
        String res = usaTesteEstatico.metodoParaTeste2();
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

`teste2` prints:

- `FOO BANANA BAR` if run after `teste1`
- `FOO null BAR` if run separately

This is precisely what you want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use static block to mock it.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;


@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UsaTesteEstaticoTest {
    @InjectMocks
    UsaTesteEstatico usaTesteEstatico;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void init(){
        Mockito.mockStatic(TesteEstatico.class);
    }

    @Test
    void teste1(){

        Mockito.when(TesteEstatico.teste())
                .thenReturn("BANANA");

        String res = usaTesteEstatico.metodoParaTeste1();
        System.out.println(res);
    }

    @Test
    void teste2(){

        Mockito.when(TesteEstatico.teste())
                .thenReturn("LARANJA");

        String res = usaTesteEstatico.metodoParaTeste2();
        System.out.println(res);

    }
}
```

Comment: This is bad advice - tests are not independent anymore

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith; 
import org.mockito.InjectMocks; 
import org.mockito.Mockito; 
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) 
public class UsaTesteEstaticoTest {

   @InjectMocks
   UsaTesteEstatico usaTesteEstatico;
    
   MockedStatic<TesteEstatico> testeEstatico;

   @BeforeClass
    public void init(){
        testeEstatico = Mockito.mockStatic(TesteEstatico.class);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void destroy(){
        testeEstatico.close();
    }

   @Test
   void teste1(){
       Mockito.when(TesteEstatico.teste())
            .thenReturn("BANANA");

       String res = usaTesteEstatico.metodoParaTeste1();
       System.out.println(res);
   }

   @Test
   void teste2(){
       Mockito.when(TesteEstatico.teste())
            .thenReturn("LARANJA");

       String res = usaTesteEstatico.metodoParaTeste2();
       System.out.println(res);

   }
}
```

None of the above-mentioned solutions posted earlier worked for me If you are having the same static methods to be mocked at multiple locations.Try this out

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).